# Convert numerical representation to human readable string

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have data in my database, which represented like :

```
&#1087;&#1088;&#1080;&#1074;&#1077;&#1090;
```

It normally looks on the page (привет), for example:

```
<h1 class="alert alert-warning ">${flashcard.nativestring}</h1>
```

but in the forms input it inserts as it is.
How to fix it ?

My form:

```
 <form:form method="POST" modelAttribute="flashcardForm" class="form-signin" >    
        <spring:bind path="nativestring">
            <div class="form-group ${status.error ? 'has-error' : ''}">
                <form:errors path="nativestring"></form:errors>
                <form:input path="nativestring" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Translation"></form:input>
            </div>
        </spring:bind>  

        <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary pull-right" type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form:form>
```

My class method code:

```
Flashcard flashcard = flashService.getFlashById(id);  
model.addAttribute("flashcardForm", flashcard);  
return "flashcards/form";
```

Comment: You need to check, if your database supports particular character encoding or not. If yes, then you need to configure it in your database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem after adding htmlEscape="false" as an attribute to my input:

```
<spring:bind path="nativestring">
            <div class="form-group ${status.error ? 'has-error' : ''}">
                <form:errors path="nativestring"></form:errors>
                <form:input path="nativestring" htmlEscape="false" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Translation"></form:input>
            </div>
        </spring:bind>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your data

```
&#1087;&#1088;&#1080;&#1074;&#1077;&#1090;
```

is html-encoding of utf-8 characters. You can convert it to a normal java string using [Apache Commons Lang](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/) :

`StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml("&#1087;&#1088;&#1080;&#1074;&#1077;&#1090;"`)

Comment: now I have a problem with saving: it saves as Ñ?Ñ?Ð²Ñ?Ñ?Ð²Ñ?Ñ?Ð², weird...

Comment: I suppose your database uses  wrong encoding for cyrrilic symbols. What is your database character encoding?

Comment: thx, solved my problem after adding htmlEscape="false" as an attribute to my input